# To Get Quarterly data with respect to a given Start and end date

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint-2010

My need is to Fetch data from a sharepoint list quarterly,ie,i pass start date and end date as parameters, taking the month of the start date,quarters have to be calculated.ie,say i pass 5th Feb 2012 as my start date then quarter begins from feb march april,and similarly for rest of the months,

Now Imagine I have december of 2012 ,jan and feb of 2013 which comprises of a quarter , in my case december's data should be comprising a quarter and jan and feb should be comprising another quarter.,
how do I approach this problem.

I must display in my output name of the car ,and total quantity of cars for a  quarter
My class difination looks like this.

```
public class Foo
{
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    public string cars { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
}

List<Foo> lst = new List<Foo>();
lst.Add(new Foo { date = Convert.ToDateTime("31/Dec/2011"), cars = "cars1", quantity = 20 });
lst.Add(new Foo { date = Convert.ToDateTime("31/Dec/2011"), cars = "cars2", quantity = 30 });
lst.Add(new Foo { date = Convert.ToDateTime("1/Jan/2012"), cars = "cars2", quantity = 80 });
lst.Add(new Foo { date = Convert.ToDateTime("11/Feb/2012"), cars = "cars1", quantity = 10 });
lst.Add(new Foo { date = Convert.ToDateTime("29/Feb/2012"), cars = "cars3", quantity = 7 });
lst.Add(new Foo { date = Convert.ToDateTime("29/May/2012"), cars = "cars3", quantity = 1 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The notion of 'quarter' is domain specific (ie business determined), so you will need to implement that yourself.

```
class Quarter {
    public static int GetQuarter(Datetime date){
        if (date >= beginningOfQuarter1 && date < endOfQuarter1){
            return 1;
        } else { ... }
    }
}

// elsewhere

int someDatesQuarter = Quarter.GetQuarter(someDate);
```

See where I'm going with this? I'm sure there are many implementations out there, and those which might be more object oriented.